# React js hover an element and disable hover when leave the element

Tags: reactjs

I have an application in react js, there is a list of elements and when the user hover over the element the background color should change to `red`. At the moment it works. Also i want when i leave  the element `unhover`, the element should be without `red` background, but now when i leave the element the color does not dissappear. Basically the hover should affect only that element where the user `hover`.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { memo, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Element = ({ id }) => {
  const styles = {
    background: "red"
  };
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      className={isHovered ? "hovered" : ""}
      onMouseOver={() => {
        setIsHovered(true);
      }}
    >
      hello {id}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {[0, 1, 2].map((el) => {
        return <Element key={el} id={el} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-einstein-9v1ws?file=/src/App.js:0-557 
 Question: Who can help to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `onMouseOver`, you can use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` to apply the styles based on the `isHovered` state.

Here is your updated code.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { memo, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Element = ({ id }) => {
  // const styles = {
  //   background: "red"
  // };
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  console.log({ isHovered });
  return (
    <div
      // style={{ backgroundColor: isHovered ? "red" : "transparent" }}
      className={"hovered"}
      // onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
      // onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
    >
      hello {id}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {[0, 1, 2].map((el) => {
        return <Element key={el} id={el} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also do the same thing using the `className` without using the `state` variable, with just targeting the hover class. I've used the both in the sandbox.

In case of doing only with `className`, you can just add a className to the div

```
className={"hovered"}
```

then, update the styles of the class in the css file.

```
.hovered:hover {
    background: red;
 }
```

[Updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-heisenberg-h1gjj?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This will not work on some use cases. If you are hovering over a nested child element (e.g a dropdown content) and this dropdown content unmounts with the use of a keyboard, for instance, there will be no mouse events triggered, therefore the isHovered state will never update